# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) in my case

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I made a little chat by jQuery, ajax and php, the concept is:

- type the message
- send it by jQuery `$.post()` to **chat.php**
- **chat.php** get the input value and write it in the **ac.htm** file
- then jQuery load the **ac.htm** to show the dialogue

Everything is ok when I was in local with WAMP, but once I put it to Github, the online test is not working, in Chrome, it shows :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)

I found lots of answers but it's not working for me, still don't understand why.

Here is the [Chat](https://jianglan1979.github.io/chat/), (*the conversation history is the local test by myself*)

Here are the [Files](https://github.com/JiangLan1979/JiangLan1979.github.io/tree/master/chat)

I put the code here too.

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Chat 聊天</legend>
        <div id="list_messages">
            <div id="messages"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="zone_input">
            <input id="nom" type="text" size="10" value="pseudo(名字)">
            <input id="message" size="30" type="text">
            <button id="send" title="send"><img src="send.png" alt="send"/></button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function (){
    afficher();
    function afficher (){
        // load the page htm to show the dialogue
        $('#messages').load('ac.htm');
    };

    // send the message to php then transfer to htm by php
    function envoyer (){
        var nom = $('#nom').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();
        $.post(
                'chat.php',
                {'nom' : nom, 'message' : message},
                afficher
              );
        $('#message').val('').focus();
    }

    // clic on the send button
    $('#send').click(function (){
        envoyer();
    });
    // type "enter"
    $(document).keyup(function (e){
        if (e.which == 13) {
            envoyer();
        };
    });
    // update the dialogue every one second
    setInterval(afficher, 1000);
});
```

php:

```
<?php

$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$ligne = '<div class="ligne"><span class="nom">' . $nom . ' : </span><span class="message">' . $message . '</span></div>';
$leFichier = file('ac.htm');
array_unshift($leFichier, $ligne);
file_put_contents('ac.htm', $leFichier);

?>
```

**Question 1**: So how to make it works?
**Question 2**: making this chat is an online course from OpenClassroom, so the teacher's code said that, at the end of the jQuery, we need to `setInterval()` to update the dialogue trom time to time, which makes sending message delayed, if I remove `setInterval()`, no more delay, but that means I can only see the dialogue updated from other user by refreshing the page, if chat from the cell phone is worse, no way to refresh, so how can I get rid of this delay?

Comment: "but once I put it to Github".... does that mean that you hosting it on Gihub pages? In that case, it won't work. Github pages only allows for static pages, which means that html-files works, but not PHP. You can only send "GET"-requests to those static pages, not "POST"-requests (therefore the "Method not allowed"-error).

Comment: To be honest,Firebase is something you want to use if you are building a real time chatting application,because they got everything you need,like real time JOSN database,login system,and many other thing you will love

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, really? So dynamic page with php can't work on Github, I didn't know that, thanks for the information.

Comment: @Felix Fong, cool! That's what I think and what I want, thanks for the information

Comment: Github pages doesn't allow for any server-side code, regardless of language (PHP, Ruby, Python, Golang, You name it...).